# Shuffle function not working on click button

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to create a memory card game using vanilla js.
I have a shuffle function that I would like to call on reset game button but it's not working.

This is what I have so far:

```
var imageList = [
        {
            name: 'image_1',
            id: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'image_2',
            id: 2
        },
        {
            name: 'image_3',
            id: 3
        },
        {
            name: 'image_4',
            id: 4
        }
    ],
    card = [],
    appendToBoard = document.getElementById('cardTable');

function shuffle(array) {
  //some code here
}

function createCardDeck() {
    shuffle(imageList); // calling shuffle(imageList)
   //some code here
 }
```

All the above works but then when I call the shuffle(imageList) on btnReset it does nothing

```
document.getElementById('btnReset').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    shuffle(imageList);
}, true);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rmbor/qnzaope7/

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your demo doesn't have a button, but in any case the click handler calls the shuffle function but doesn't repaint or update the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do two things:

1. Add `var card = '';` to `createCardDeck` function to clear it before adding markup:

   ```
   function createCardDeck() {
       shuffle(imageList);
       var card = '';
       for (var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {...}
   }
   ```
2. Replace `shuffle(imageList)` with `createCardDeck()` in your `addEventListener` function:

   ```
   document.getElementById('btnReset').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       createCardDeck();
   }, true);
   ```

Check demo - [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/qnzaope7/1/)